# Is there any command to find which header file needs to be included for certain type (not function)?

Tags: c, linux

For library functions I use `man <function>` to find which header file I need to include. But for types like `size_t`, `uint32_t`, etc. the `man` approach doesn't work.

Is there any command to find the header file required?

Comment: I would recommend to download a [draft version of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). Then in your pdf viewer, go to Annex B Library summary and do a search (whole words only). It will work for most things, unfortunately except uint32_t, since the C standard calls it `uintN_t`.

Comment: Note that `size_t` is a tricky one since quite a number of headers can be included to define it (`<stddef.h>` is the smallest, but `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, <stdlib.h>` also define it — at minimum).  `uint32_t` is defined by including `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is  `open http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/<type>` which relies on an external web page.

Comment: It is C++ though. For example, a search for `_Generic` gives me `std::generic_category`, which is hardly what I wanted.

Comment: It has both C++ and C. For example [/c/types/size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) gives C's `size_t` and [/cpp/types/size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) gives C++'s `std::size_t`

Comment: Apparently it just doesn't know about C11.

Comment: It does know about C11,  `_Generic` is not under `/c/types/` but `language/_Generic` I guess it's not a type per se. [_Generic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Generic).  For actual types (where you need the `#include`) the answer kind of works.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to search locally using grep.

Something like `grep -r 'typedef\s.*\suint32_t;' /usr/include` should work for you.

Comment: Up to a point…the problem being that `uint32_t` might well be typedef'd in a header in `/usr/include/bits` or `/usr/include/sys` even though the header that should be included is some other header altogether (nominally `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h` for this specific type).  This tells you which header it _is_ defined in, but not which header you should be including to gain access to the definition.